# Why does a .gdb I created with GDAL double in size after it's been modified in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, gdal, file-geodatabase

I created a large (over 200 million features) .gdb file with Python/GDAL. I had to move it to my Windows machine to add and calculate a column in Arc, since I couldn't figure out how to do with GDAL. The only difference was the addition of the one long integer column, but when I move it back to my Linux VM, the .gdb is now double the size (244G vs 112G).

Why is that and is there anything I can do to change it?

Relatedly, a .gdb I had created earlier using the same data and process (but for a different part of the world) had almost 5 times fewer features (44.6 mil), but is 12.2 times smaller than new .gdb (20G vs. 244G). Granted, there are 9 fewer columns, but this still doesn't make sense to me. Another interesting thing is that this .gdb, when I created and calculated the column in Arc a few months ago, had `SHAPE_Length` and `SHAPE_Area` added as columns, which I assumed was an Arc thing. This time, however, those fields were not added.

Anyone has some insight as to why I may be seeing this behavior? I am just trying to understand.

Comment: have you tried [compacting](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/compact-file-and-personal-geodatabases.htm) it?

Comment: @JGH no but i will, thanks for the tip. should i compress as well?

Comment: A [compressed](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-compressing-vs-compacting.htm) geodatabase becomes read-only

Comment: Adding a column results in duplication of the source table for the duration of the copy event. The interim data is deleted, but the high-water mark is not reset until the table is compacted.

Comment: @Vince ah, there it is. this makes sense. thanks!

Comment: interestingly enough, the Compact process completed with no error, but Windows is still showing my .gdb as 244GB. Not what I was expecting

Comment: Hmmm.. It seems the last data page is at the end of the file. You can try to compress and uncompress, though that's going to take quite a while (a simple copy-delete-rename might be faster),  I try to avoid tables in excess of 8-10M rows, with 50-60M being the absolute limit.  I'm also allergic to adding columns to large tables *in-situ*, so I'm not likely to have encountered this, umm..., feature of FGDB.